# Login page is returned always even though sessions are handled

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

- JMeter version 5.x and 4.0
- Protocol : Https

### Steps

1. Start creating a test plan with a recording template
2. Configure the **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** with HTTPS domain, target controller 
   [image]
3. Save the test plan and start the proxy server
4. Configure Firefox with security certificate and proxy details
5. Access the login page https://www.systemname.com . Request is recorded
6. Login to the system with valid credentials. Request is recorded successfully 
   [image]
7. Add a Boundary value Extractor post processor to extract session variable (LCSRF_VAL) and replace the session value recorded in the login request with ${LCSRF_VAL}
   [image]
8. Save the test plan and run the test
9. Check the responses in View Result Tree --> HTML view

### Actual Outcome

User is not logged into the system. Login page is returned.

### Expected Outcome

User should be able to login when sessions are handled

### Note :

It worked fine if recording started from a URL of a page inside the system. For example 
https://www.system.com/en/administration/Search?nav=Administration

Comment: You seem to have done everything correct. At this point, I can only suggest you to record your script in FireFox AFTER clearing all the cookies against your www.system.com domain to simulate private browsing. or recording it in private mode so that you can make sure that your application is treating it like a fresh session and can send all set-cookie and header initialization for generating a valid CSRF token. I am making this comment based on your "Note" at the end

Comment: Thank you @Selva. Let me give a try again with the private mode in Firefox.

Comment: It did not work with the private mode too. It was possible go into the system with following in HTTP Request path /en/administration/login.jsp?nav=Administration&forward=..%2F..%2Fen%2Fadministration%2FSearch.jsp. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It worked well with a sample system https://qa.moodle.net/login/index.php. Not sure what is wrong with the actual system under test.

Comment: Can you compare all the HTTP request & response headers while using it manually vs the ones generated by the JMeter script and see any differences? If all the headers and cookies are the same and the script is sending the accurate/valid CSRF, I cannot imagine why the script should fail.

Comment: @Selva Is there a possibility for you to give help directly?